# Why is Silverlight toast notification only available in OOB app?

Tags: silverlight

I haven't been able to find an explanation, or think of a reason why it's not available in non-OOB apps.  So why is the toast notification only available in OOB apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silverlight 4 Out-Of-Browser apps can operate in full trust.  This is necessary to open a window separate from the primary window.  Toast notifications are separate windows.

Comment: That makes sense, but I guess that begs the question why Microsoft didn't make the notification an in-app dialog, like the message box, when running in browser. Thanks for the answer though.