# Silverlight Notification API in-browser

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, notifications, toast, out-of-browser

I'd like to use the Notification API to create toast notifications for a Silverlight app designed to run both in and out of the browser, but the [NotificationWindow class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.notificationwindow%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) is only available OOB.

Does there exist anything that can replicate the behaviour inside the app? My idea is to have a container in the bottom right of the screen overlaying all other content. Then, create a wrapper which detects OOB-mode, passing params to the Notification API if possible, or populating and showing my own container if not. Is there anything that does this available?

It seems strange that MS chose not to implement something like this, [as has been pointed out before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6684366/why-is-silverlight-toast-notification-only-available-in-oob-app).

Comment: I have also considered using a Javascript solution ([for example](http://christopheargento.com/2011/03/02/silverlight-toast-notification-in-out-of-browser-via-jquery-plugin/)), but I'd prefer to use a pure-xaml solution rather than use the HTML bridge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Displaying a notification in browser is simple. You just need to use a popup and make it appear in the right place. See the following [post as an example](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/silverlight/Displaying-Notification-Messages-in-a-Silverlight-Dashboard-Application.aspx).

Now the difference with that approach is that the notification will show inside the browser. In OOB it shows outside the window and it's visible even if the windows is minimized. Due to security reasons it's not possible to directly do this.

Out of interest, Chrome Applications like Tweetdeck and Gmail, are able to display notifications outside of the browser. I think this might be a possiblity, but not exactly a Silverlight and cross browser solution.